# Incorrect content type for PDF file with Firefox

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, firefox, mime-types

I am using Spring 3.2.0.M2 and I am trying to upload a pdf file.

JSP file :

```
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data>
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file.getContentType());
    //prints "application/text-plain:formatted"
}
```

I am using the Standard multipart resolver :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <multipart-config />
</servlet>
```

with :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

I also tried with CommonsMultipartResolver from Apache but the problem is the same.

What I am getting is "application/text-plain:formatted" instead of "application/pdf".
I tested with several pdf file (from different sources). When I try to upload another file type (e.g. Word document), it works as expected (for a Word document, I get "application/msword").

I intend to store the content type (and the file name) into a database for later retrieval and download of the file. Having an incorrect content type is then causing an exception when calling setContentType like this :

```
public void downloadResource(@RequestParam("resId") Long resourceId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // get resource with its id.
    response.setContentType(resource.getContentType());
    //throws org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.TokenMgrError
}
```

The exception message is :

> Lexical error at line 1, column 23. Encountered: ":" (58), after : ""

Comment: Related: [Content type for file part of the multipart/form-data request is set wrong by the client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11009706/95735)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem with a .svg file.

**Solved it by modifying** the Mozilla Firefox **[mimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf)** file in the [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder). (thx to Piotrs Link above)

For other people having a similar problem. This was caused due to a mistakenly set Content-Type in my PHP script. When first testing the script (it delivered a svg file indirectly via php) i had another Content-Type set in the header().

```
header("Content-Type: image/svg+xml"); //should have been
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive"); //was actually set
```

This now overruled the content type setting in the firefox mimeTypes.rdf file:

```
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:application/vnd.android.package-archive"
                   NC:value="application/vnd.android.package-archive"
                   NC:editable="true"
                   NC:fileExtensions="svg"
                   NC:description="Scalable Vector Graphics">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/vnd.android.package-archive"/>
  </RDF:Description>
```

Probably because FF thinks its seeing a "new" file/filetype - and adding it to its config.

To fix this, you only need to delete the wrong XML section in the mimeTypes.rdf and restart FF of course.